# Transform array uplevel array elements?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Have an $x as array:

```
$x1 = array(
   0=>array("up1", -10, 1, 1, 2.5),
   19=>array("up2",-4, 1.2, 2, 0.5)
);
```

I want to transform `$x1` Became  `x2` like this:

```
     $x2 = Array(
    'A'=>
        array(
        "up1"=>array(-10, 1, 1, 2.5),
        "up2"=>array(-4, 1.2, 2, 0.5)
        )
      );
```

Anybody can told help me algorithm to do this:?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$x2 = array();
foreach ($x1 as $x) {
    $key = array_shift($x);
    $x2['A'][$key] = $x;
}
```

Or, if you want to be really clever:

```
$x2 = array();
foreach ($x1 as $x) {
    $x2['A'][array_shift($x)] = $x;
}
```

Comment: Very cool, didn't know about array_shift(). Always learning something new on here!

Comment: @Mike There are a many useful [array functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). Since arrays are what pretty much everything evolves around in PHP, you should really take the time to skim through them. One day you'll find a use for one. @IEnAk ...yet not accepted. :-( (Just kidding, I really don't need the points. ;o)))

Answer (score 1):

```
$x2 = array();
$i  = 0;
foreach ( $x1 as $data ) {
    if ( empty($x2['A']) ) {
        $x2['A'] = array();
    }

    $x2['A'][ array_shift($data) ] = $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this out

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $x1[$i] != NULL ; $i++ ) {
  $x1[$i] = 'a'=>($x1[$i]);
  for ( $j = 0 ; $x1[$i][$j] != NULL; $j++ ) {
    $x1[$i][$j] = 'up'.$j=> $x1[$i][$j];
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `for` loops, don't make the condition `$x1[$i] != NULL`, it throws notices! Also, you have syntax errors with weirdly placed `=>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about it. Not the best way but, it works fine.

```
$x1 = array(
  0=>array("up1", -10, 1, 1, 2.5),
  19=>array("up2",-4, 1.2, 2, 0.5)
);

$x2 = array( 'A' => array() );

foreach($x1 as $current) {
  $key = $current[0];
  unset($current[0]);
  $x2['A'][$key] = $current;
}
```